# Laravel passport consuming api with js not working

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-passport

I am trying to consume my api using ajax (axios) request as the way it is instructed in laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript). But it is not working, shows errors like the following image

[image]

My sample header response looks likes the following:

[image]

My ajax request looks like this:

```
   axios.get('http://localhost:81/test_laravel/public/api/user')
            .then(function(response){
                console.log('Component mounted.')
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error.response.status)
            });
```

Don't have a clue what is going on. Please help.

Comment: @iCoders I have updated my question.

Comment: Header is not required for js consumers

Comment: probably you need to be authenticated to access that api

Comment: @Faramarz I need to be authenticated by what? Do you know any way around?

Comment: i haven't use api auth but you can find it in the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication

Comment: Passport is the way around for api auth.

Comment: Any route that goes through the API file will need to use some type of auth.  If you installed passport it'll be through tokens.  Read up on the documentation but you must first call your API to retireve a token with login credentials or you can go for an implicit grant type.  But without the token verification you will not get what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works if I make a change in the \App\Http\EncryptCookies.php file like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter as EncrypterContract;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies as Middleware;

class EncryptCookies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The names of the cookies that should not be encrypted.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $serialize = true;

    protected $except = [
        //
    ];

    public function __construct(EncrypterContract $encrypter)
    {
        parent::__construct($encrypter);
    }
}
```

Changing the value of $serializable by adding the line `protected static $serialize = true;` works.