# Laravel passport auth through CreateFreshApiToken always returns {"message":"Unauthenticated."}

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am trying to allow my users, once they are logged in, to consume my own API through Javasscript as described there https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

I have installed Passport. My web middleware is defined as

```
'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class,
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
    ],
```

I see that a "laravel_token" cookie seems indeed to be created after login.

I've then tried sending a simple get request to an API route

```
window.$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://mywebsite.test/api/testApi',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.error(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

The only response I manage to get is

```
{"message":"Unauthenticated."}
```

What can I have missed?

**Update**

The request is performed from a subdomain, client.mywebsite.test, and after investigation that's what seems to be the issue. Authentication works well when performing the ajax call from mywebsite.test. How can I fix that for the subdomain?

Request headers when requesting from subdomain:

```
OPTIONS /api/testApi HTTP/1.1
Host: mywebsite.test
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: https://client.mywebsite.test
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-csrf-token,x-requested-with
Accept: */*
Referer: https://client.mywebsite.test/home
```

Request headers when requesting from domain:

```
GET /api/testApi HTTP/1.1
Host: mywebsite.test
Connection: keep-alive
X-CSRF-TOKEN: fLTkaq9p62FROutzch2iE9IF864al8adFnxptbve
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Cookie: laravel_token=[...]; XSRF-TOKEN=[...]; mywebsite_session=[...];
```

Comment: and you have the meta tag csrf-token set up correctly?

Comment: Yep.. I would like to check if my GET request actually attaches the laravel_token but I can't see any cookies being sent with the request in the Chrome web developer tools..

Comment: Could you edit your answer with your `web` middleware stack?

Comment: I've added that - thanks

Comment: same error here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing and browsing and browsing..

Turns out the problem comes, indeed, from the cookies not being sent with the request for CORS. I fixed it by adding "withCredentials" to my Ajax call:

```
window.$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
    },
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://mywebsite.test/api/testApi',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.error(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

You also need to ensure the headers for your response specify that credentials are accepted:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in a Laravel 5.6 project:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies as Middleware;

class EncryptCookies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The names of the cookies that should not be encrypted.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $serialize = true;

    /**
     * The names of the cookies that should not be encrypted.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
    ];
}
```

Set the property `$serialize` to `true` on `EncryptCookies` middleware.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade#upgrade-5.6.30

Source: [Laravel passport consuming api with js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422686/laravel-passport-consuming-api-with-js-not-working)